# How can I convert a Bundle to a PersistableBundle?

Tags: android, bundle, shortcut, job-scheduling

API21 released the [`PersistableBundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PersistableBundle.html) which is a bundle that the system retains for various purposes ([`JobScheduler` jobs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html), [`ShortcutInfo`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutInfo.html#getExtras()) etc). I'd like an easy way to convert the `Bundle`'s that are present in my old code to `PersistableBundle`'s...how can I do it?

Comment: I imagine you'll get a limited space for what you're saving. Anyway, instead of carpet bombing go for a precision strike i.e. save what you need to recover after a reboot and nothing else. /// `JobInfo.Builder.setExtras` accepts a `PersistableBundle` only. So if you create one directly you don't even touch regular `Bundle` and there's nothing to convert.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment. I'm just making sure you're not solving an artificial problem (a problem that shouldn't occur in the first place).

Comment: As an example for a use case where the conversion is necessary, what if I wish to call a jobservice one a user clicks a notification? The notification would have a pending intent, where the extras are a `Bundle`, but it needs to pass the data again to the service, which uses a `PersistableBundle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of API26, there is no way exposed to easily do this, you have to manually verify that the values are compatible:

```
private boolean bundleCanBePersisted(final Bundle extras) {
    if (extras == null) {
        return true;
    }

    Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
    Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
    boolean allExtrasPersistable = true;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next();
        boolean isPersistable = isPersistable(extras.get(key));

        if (!isPersistable) {
            LOGGER.warning("Non persistable value in bundle. " + bundleItemToString(key, extras));
        }

        allExtrasPersistable &= isPersistable;
    }
    return allExtrasPersistable;
}

/**
 * These are all the values that can be put into a PersistableBundle.
 */
private boolean isPersistable(final Object o) {
    return o == null
            || o instanceof PersistableBundle
            || o instanceof String
            || o instanceof String[]
            || o instanceof Boolean
            || o instanceof Boolean[]
            || o instanceof Double
            || o instanceof Double[]
            || o instanceof Integer
            || o instanceof Integer[]
            || o instanceof Long
            || o instanceof Long[];
}

private String bundleItemToString(final String key, final Bundle bundle) {
    Object value = bundle.get(key);
    Class<?> valueClazz = null;
    if (value != null) {
        valueClazz = value.getClass();
    }
    return String.format("[%s = %s (%s)]", key, value, valueClazz);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a utility that actually converts a `Bundle` to a `PersistableBundle` and back:

```
/**
 * Creates a new {@link Bundle} based on the specified {@link PersistableBundle}.
 */
public static Bundle toBundle(PersistableBundle persistableBundle) {
    if (persistableBundle == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putAll(persistableBundle);
    return bundle;
}

/**
 * Creates a new {@link PersistableBundle} from the specified {@link Bundle}.
 * Will ignore all values that are not persistable, according
 * to {@link #isPersistableBundleType(Object)}.
 */
public static PersistableBundle toPersistableBundle(Bundle bundle) {
    if (bundle == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PersistableBundle persistableBundle = new PersistableBundle();
    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
        Object value = bundle.get(key);
        if (isPersistableBundleType(value)) {
            putIntoBundle(persistableBundle, key, value);
        }
    }
    return persistableBundle;
}

/**
 * Checks if the specified object can be put into a {@link PersistableBundle}.
 *
 * @see <a href="https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/PersistableBundle.java#49">PersistableBundle Implementation</a>
 */
public static boolean isPersistableBundleType(Object value) {
    return ((value instanceof PersistableBundle) ||
            (value instanceof Integer) || (value instanceof int[]) ||
            (value instanceof Long) || (value instanceof long[]) ||
            (value instanceof Double) || (value instanceof double[]) ||
            (value instanceof String) || (value instanceof String[]) ||
            (value instanceof Boolean) || (value instanceof boolean[])
    );
}

/**
 * Attempts to insert the specified key value pair into the specified bundle.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the value type can not be put into the bundle.
 */
public static void putIntoBundle(BaseBundle baseBundle, String key, Object value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to determine type of null values");
    } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
        baseBundle.putInt(key, (int) value);
    } else if (value instanceof int[]) {
        baseBundle.putIntArray(key, (int[]) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Long) {
        baseBundle.putLong(key, (long) value);
    } else if (value instanceof long[]) {
        baseBundle.putLongArray(key, (long[]) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Double) {
        baseBundle.putDouble(key, (double) value);
    } else if (value instanceof double[]) {
        baseBundle.putDoubleArray(key, (double[]) value);
    } else if (value instanceof String) {
        baseBundle.putString(key, (String) value);
    } else if (value instanceof String[]) {
        baseBundle.putStringArray(key, (String[]) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        baseBundle.putBoolean(key, (boolean) value);
    } else if (value instanceof boolean[]) {
        baseBundle.putBooleanArray(key, (boolean[]) value);
    } else if (value instanceof PersistableBundle) {
        if (baseBundle instanceof PersistableBundle)
            ((PersistableBundle) baseBundle).putPersistableBundle(key, (PersistableBundle)value);
        else if (baseBundle instanceof Bundle)
            ((Bundle) baseBundle).putBundle(key, toBundle((PersistableBundle) value));
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Objects of type " + value.getClass().getSimpleName()
                + " can not be put into a " + BaseBundle.class.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

You can find the complete class and unit tests in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Steppschuh/31ce136673ce8057a2468cf8f576b3c1).

Comment: This does not handle nested bundles properly, instead it flattens them out.
In particular, `putIntoBundle` should be using `putPersistableBundle(key, ...)` instead of `putAll`.

Comment: Is there any way to add `Parcelable` Object into `Persistable bundle`?

Answer (score -1):

**Converting form Bundle to PersistableBundle**

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
PersistableBundle pb = new PersistableBundle(b);
```

**Converting from PersistableBundle  to Bundle**

```
PersistableBundle pb = new PersistableBundle();
Bundle b= new Bundle();
b.putAll(pb);
```

Comment: This conversion is not possible.