# Using API 26 call - transientExtras in API 23 Android

Tags: android, bundle, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler, transient

I am trying to add `extras` to my `JobInfo.Builder` supporting Android API 23 and higher. Thing is when adding `Bundle` to `builder` then I need to do `builder.setTransientExtras`.

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, RestApiJobService.class);

JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(getUniqueJobId(), serviceComponent);

builder.setTransientExtras(RestApiJobFactory.save(jobItem);
```

The issue here is that `builder.setTransientExtras` is only supported in API 26 and higher. And `builder.setExtras` only supports `PersistableBundle`. And I need it to support `Bundle` since I have `Files` in my `Bundle`.

Is there any workaround to support `builder.setTransientExtras` in Android 23 and also the same for `getTransientExtras`.

Or maybe there is a way to use Bundle with `bundle.setExtras()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `builder.setTransientExtras` can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when `build()` is called on the `JobInfo.Builder` for persisted jobs. Safer to use `PersistableBundle` and restrict the content of the bundle to persistable types, e.g. `Long`, `Double`, `String` and nested `PersistableBundle` plus others. If you can modify the `RestApiJobFactory` class, instead of returning a `Bundle` that passes around `File` objects, try storing the `File` locations as `String`. If you can't, write a helper method to convert your `Bundle` to a `PeristableBundle`, extracting the `File` info in the process. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178007/949224 for an example.

The principle for persisted jobs is to reduce the extras down to basic peristable types, and when in the job itself is running, the complex transient types should be constructed.

Comment: I will look into converting the bundle, but storing files as `file.absolutePath` is what I ended up doing for now and it seems to work well (have not tried it with `Persistablebundle yet because I have a list of those locations). The last issue I have is that I have a really big object that is `Parcelable` and I am passing it with `putParcelable` and `getParcelable`. Is it safe to convert `Parcelable` and an `ArrayList<String>` with the method that you sent?

Comment: You're on the right track from what I can gather. You can create an appropriate key and save `file.absolutePath` in the `PersistableBundle`. On second question, how big is this Parcelable object?

Comment: How do I answer that how big it is. It has multiple `Parcelable` objects inside of it, which have their own `Parcelable` objects and I would say it is rather big. Around 6 `Objects` inside of the first one and two of them have their own `objects` inside which each have one more `object` inside.

Comment: You should be fine. It only really becomes an issue with thousands of nested persistable objects.There is a limit set on for the internal service binder transaction buffer of 1MB by default. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html.

Comment: Well thank you for your answer, I will try to implement it tomrrow or next week and let you know if I got it working. Since the bounty is expiring I will give it to you and hope it works.

Comment: well it seems that it is not converting my `ArrayList<String>` to `PersistableBundle` nor the `Parcelable` Object. I suppose that maybe If I did `String[]` of image paths' it would persist that data, but the `Parcelable object` is still the problem.

Comment: By converting the `Parcelable` into `JSON String` first and then saving putting it as a `String` into the `Bundle` worked, so i got it working